# rails skip_before_filter within method (after other before_filters have been run)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, before-filter

In application_controller.rb I have the following:

```
before_filter :get_events
before_filter :get_sitemap
def login_required
    return true if session[:user]
    # If we get to this point, I want to avoid running get_events and get_sitemap
    flash[:warning] = 'Please login to continue'
    redirect_to login_users_url
    return false 
end
```

And in other controllers I have for example:

```
before_filter :login_required, :except => [:show]
```

So essentially I have methods running that access the database for all pages except I don't want it to happen when the user is required to log in (i.e., being redirected from a page where normally get_events and get_sitemap are required).

I realize one way of doing this is to run login_required as a before_filter on ALL controllers before any other before_filters are set and then exclude certain controller models but I'd like to know if there's a way of doing it without having to change all my controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after considering Joshua's answer I still couldn't get what I wanted to go for...so what I did was do a little hybrid solution. All controllers still reference ApplicationController, but within ApplicationController I always run the `before_filter :login_required` FIRST before other before_filters. Redirects in rails seem to stop other before_filters from running, which is what I wanted. In the other controllers I use the `skip_before_filter :login_required, :only => [:this_time]` wherever necessary.

Comment: What exactly does the :only => [:this_time] option do?

Comment: :this_time is not a real method; I just wrote that as 'pseudo-code'. You'd use the method name of the controller action you want to skip logins for...so [:create, :update...] so on and so forth.

Answer (score 4):

For something like this, I usually create an `AuthenticatedController` (in app/controllers/authenticated_controller.rb):

```
class AuthenticatedController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :require_login

end
```

Then I derive all controllers requiring authentication from that, specifying a `skip_before_filter :require_login` for actions I want to exclude on a controller-by-controller basis. For example:

```
class PlanetsController < AuthenticatedController

  skip_before_filter :require_login, only: [:index]

end
```

This will require you to change all controllers, but only for the purpose of deriving from `AuthenticatedController`. As far as I know this is a perfectly acceptable way of handling it, and I don't think there's a way outside of monkey patching ActionController::Base to make this apply to all controllers, which is a pretty bad idea for a variety of reasons.

Comment: How do I do that? I tried class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController in conjunction with class ContactsController < AuthenticationController and I get the error uninitialized constant AuthenticationController

Comment: Did you put it in the file app/controllers/authentication_controller.rb?

Comment: Stupid mistake, the file was there but it wasn't named properly...I named it as "AuthenticationController.rb" instead of "authentication_controller.rb". It's fixed and working, however I have the same problem...within the ApplicationController.rb file, I want to use skip_before_filter :get_events but only on the condition that the user is actually logged in.

Comment: Since `skip_before_filter` doesn't take an :if parameter (which would be kinda nice), you'll have to check for that in the `get_events` method, maybe by returning early or wrapping the code to execute in an if statement.